# Changing GridView Cell template to specific Color in Xaml

Tags: binding

I have a Gridview, and I am binding a collection with it, Now I want to change the Color of a single column depending upon the bool value, if it is +ve then background should be Blue and If -ve then display the background as yellow. 
I tried with Data trigger, and with using converters also, But can't get the things done.

**the xaml file is**

```
  <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key=" ColorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentPrice}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PriceStatus}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PriceStatus}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Block.Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>           
    </Grid.Resources>
```

...
...
..
.

```
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ColorStyle}"
                                       />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

**and Using converter also.**

public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return Brushes.Blue;
        else
            return Brushes.Yellow;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

**xaml file**
  
            
                -->
                
                
                    
                        
                    
                    
                        
                    
                -->
            
            
        
.
.
.

```
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ColorStyle}"
                                       Background="{Binding PriceStatus, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"
                                       />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

PriceStatus is CLR boolean Property, it sets to false for -ve value of CurrentPrice.

Thanks